# Force DateTime.TryParse to be UTC by changing the string value input

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a config file that asks for a date in a specific format:

```
"StartDate": "2017-05-27"
```

This number gets used as follows:

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime.TryParse(MyConfig.StartDate, out startDate);
```

I realised when this ran on servers that are in different time zones, the DateTime returned may not be UTC kind and thus further operations to that DateTime, like Ticks, or something else, could cause the time to possibly get skewed.

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime.TryParse("2017-05-27", out startDate);

if(startDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
{
    "Ohhh yeah".Dump();
}
else
{
    "EH OH".Dump();
}

startDate.Dump();
```

If i change the string to `"2017-05-27Z"` it does not force it to be `DateTimeKind.Utc`... as it still outputs *"EH OH"* but interestingly the time output by the `startDate.Dump()` does indeed change by an hour, but its kind does not change :(.

How can i force the configuration string to be correctly parsed as a UTC DateTime? (without changing the TryParse code, i am aware it has a kind specifier) - It may not be possible, but that's the question... is it :)

Comment: I don't think you can. The overload of `TryParse` you're using is one of the originals, I believe, and *predate* the existence of `DateTimeKind` (introduced in .NET 2.0). Setting the `Kind` to anything other than `Local` would probably have been considered a breaking change.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: What happens if you use this TryParseExact instead? `DateTime.TryParseExact("2017-06-06", "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime startDate);`

Comment: Well you can also use the TryParse with the signature of Kind... Alas, i wanted to avoid a 50+ client re-deployment with updated code, by forcing it to be UTC with the Z added in configuration.

Comment: So you have easier access to the config file than your client code? In that case, maybe you just need to specify a time as well for your date string. So instead of `2017-05-27Z` you could try `2017-05-27 00:00:00Z` (ISO standard says the Z should be behind the time, not the date)

Comment: @GTHvidsten - Thanks for the tip. I have easy access to both client code and config. It's just a re-deployment of a new version of the code will take the Ops teams about a week to push out and check. A configuration change on the other hand is a simple redeployment through Octopus. :D